# Display a list of plots in a grid with specified columns and rows based on grouping column values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706753/how-do-i-arrange-a-variable-list-of-plots-using-grid-arrange) post which seems to be the 'main' one for my question. However, I don't quite have what I need and wanted to see if there's any other solutions out there...

I have a list column data frame with some plots, similar to this:

```
exdata <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  nest %>% 
  crossing(dummy = 1:3) %>% 
  mutate(plots = map(.x = data, ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()))
```

Looks like this:

```
exdata
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   cut       data                  dummy plots 
   <ord>     <list>                <int> <list>
 1 Fair      <tibble [1,610 × 9]>      1 <gg>  
 2 Fair      <tibble [1,610 × 9]>      2 <gg>  
 3 Fair      <tibble [1,610 × 9]>      3 <gg>  
 4 Good      <tibble [4,906 × 9]>      1 <gg>  
 5 Good      <tibble [4,906 × 9]>      2 <gg>  
 6 Good      <tibble [4,906 × 9]>      3 <gg>  
 7 Very Good <tibble [12,082 × 9]>     1 <gg>  
 8 Very Good <tibble [12,082 × 9]>     2 <gg>  
 9 Very Good <tibble [12,082 × 9]>     3 <gg>  
10 Premium   <tibble [13,791 × 9]>     1 <gg>  
11 Premium   <tibble [13,791 × 9]>     2 <gg>  
12 Premium   <tibble [13,791 × 9]>     3 <gg>  
13 Ideal     <tibble [21,551 × 9]>     1 <gg>  
14 Ideal     <tibble [21,551 × 9]>     2 <gg>  
15 Ideal     <tibble [21,551 × 9]>     3 <gg>
```

Column exdata$plots is a list of ggplots.

I would like to plot these in a similar outcome to using facet_grid based on columns of cut and dummy of dummys. The first column would be all the plots for Fair, the second for Good, the third for Very good etc.  The rows would be titled '1', '2' and '3' for each value in dummy. A 3 * 5 grid.

I tried the Patchwork package but this does not have a 'direct' way of doing this. Ideally I'd have the column titles clearly labelled with the corresponding  cut and then the rows with the corresponding rows.

Note my particular use case prevents me from building a master data frame and wrangling it to use facet grid in the desired manner, I'm really stuck with a list column in a data frame like above.

[Edit based on comments].
Adding more detail to the above paragraph, I'm using a package to generate a model and then plot the model. `CLVTools::plot(model)` on each row in my df. So the plots are already generated by an existing model within a `dplyr::mutate` chunk. I don't create the plots myself, they are done by the package with some customizations that I'd rather not go into battle with R to replicate manually.

How can I assemble my list column of plots into a 3*5 grid with clear column and row titles, like with facet_grid?

Comment: what about using gridextra? `library(gridExtra)` 
`do.call("grid.arrange", c(dat$plots, ncol = 5))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very programmatic in nature, but at least it works. I was inspired by [Allan Camerons's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65292313/13095326).

We can use `patchwork::wrap_plots` to get the ggplot graphs into a grid.

Then we can use `grid::grid.draw` to draw some `textGrobs` manually. You can define the position on the final graph with the `x=` and `y=` arguments to `textGrob`. Since the position is different for each label, we can use `purrr:walk2` to combine sets of parameters. (`walk2` is like `map2`, but doen't return anything.) The `rot=` argument can turn the text depending on the axis.

```
library(patchwork); library(purrr); library(grid)
wrap_plots(plotlist = exdata$plots, ncol = 3, nrow = 5) +
  plot_annotation(title = " ")
walk2(seq(0.125,0.875,length.out = 5),unique(exdata$cut),
      ~grid.draw(textGrob(.y, x = 0.01, y = .x, rot = 90)))
walk2(seq(0.165,0.835,length.out = 3),unique(exdata$dummy),
      ~grid.draw(textGrob(.y, x = .x, y = 0.98, rot = 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. Why `seq(0.125,0.875, ...`?

Comment: I'm going to leave this question open for a while too, just in case. But this solution is very much appreciated.

Comment: Ah that's what the seq(0.125.... is doing? Pickign the location of the labels? OK

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the data why not directly generate the figure (or do you just have a list of plots), instead of nesting them? Something like:

```
diamonds %>%
   group_by(cut) %>% 
   nest %>% 
   crossing(dummy = 1:3) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
   geom_point(data = . %>% unnest(data)) +
   facet_grid(dummy ~ cut)
```

Then you can adjust labels in the standard fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this won't work for me (or it would be pretty inefficient). I'm using a package, CLVTools which fits a model and then generates a plot with e.g. `plot(model)`. So each row in my real data contains a plot based on the model for a rows data segment. DOing what you have about would require refitting all the models again just for the plot and my real life list column df is pretty long.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense (and what I was hoping wasn't the case!)

Comment: @IanCampbell added an EDIT comment to my post.